# Fully Parsing Timestamps in Golang

Tags: json, postgresql, datetime, go, unmarshalling

I'm trying to make a simple tool which parses JSON-formatted lines in a file and performs an `INSERT` operation into a database.

I have a struct which looks like this:

```
type DataBlob struct {
  ....
  Datetime time.Time `json:"datetime, string"`
  ....
}
```

And parsing code which looks like this:

```
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
// Loop through all lines in the file
for scanner.Scan() {
    var t DataBlob

    // Decode the line, parse the JSON
    dec := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(scanner.Text()))
    if err := dec.Decode(&t);
    err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Perform the database operation
    executionString: = "INSERT INTO observations (datetime) VALUES ($1)"
    _, err := db.Exec(executionString, t.Datetime)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

My JSON file has lines, each containing a `datetime` value that looks like this:

```
{ "datetime": 1465793854 }
```

When the `datetime` is formatted as a Unix timestamp, the Marshaller complains:

```
panic: parsing time "1465793854" as ""2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"": cannot parse "1465793854" as """
```

---

In the script that generates the JSON (also written in Golang), I tried simply printing the String representation of the `Time.time` type, producing the following:

```
{ "datetime": "2016-06-13 00:23:34 -0400 EDT" }
```

To which the Marshaller complains when I go to parse it:

```
panic: parsing time ""2016-06-13 00:23:34 -0400 EDT"" as ""2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"": cannot parse " 00:23:34 -0400 EDT"" as "T"
```

If I also treat this timestamp (which looks pretty standard) as a String and avoid the Marshaling problem, Postgres complains when I try to perform the insertion:

```
panic: pq: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "2016-06-13 00:23:34 -0400 EDT"
```

This is frustrating on a number of levels, but mainly because if I serialize a `Time.time` type, I would think it should still be understood at the other side of the process.

How can I go about parsing this timestamp to perform the database insertion? Apologizes for the lengthy question and thanks for your help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

JSON unmarshalling of `time.Time` [expects](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.UnmarshalJSON) date string to be in RFC 3339 format.

So in your golang program that generates the JSON, instead of simply printing the `time.Time` value, use [Format](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format) to print it in RFC 3339 format.

```
t.Format(time.RFC3339)
```

> if I serialize a Time.time type, I would think it should still be
>   understood at the other side of the process

If you used the [Marshaller interface](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.MarshalJSON) with the serializing, it would indeed output the date in RFC 3339 format. So the other side of the process will understand it. So you can do that as well.

```
d := DataBlob{Datetime: t}
enc := json.NewEncoder(fileWriter)
enc.Encode(d)
```

Comment: what if you have have no control over the JSON input? what would be the solution then

Comment: @techunter a custom unmarshaller

Answer (score 5):

For reference, if you need custom unmarshalling with time types you need to create your own type with the UnmarshalJSON method. Here's an example:

```
type Timestamp struct {
    time.Time
}

// UnmarshalJSON decodes an int64 timestamp into a time.Time object
func (p *Timestamp) UnmarshalJSON(bytes []byte) error {
    // 1. Decode the bytes into an int64
    var raw int64
    err := json.Unmarshal(bytes, &raw)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error decoding timestamp: %s\n", err)
        return err
    }

    // 2. Parse the unix timestamp
    p.Time = time.Unix(raw, 0)
    return nil
}
```

Then use the type in your struct:

```
type DataBlob struct {
  ....
  Datetime Timestamp `json:"datetime"`
  ....
}
```